# VHDL logical operation on integer

Tags: vhdl

I have some VHDL code that has the following signal definition:

```
signal hcount  : integer range 0 to 235;
```

This is used as a counter throughout my system (so I believe it needs to continue as an integer and not be declared as a std_logic_vector for example), but I also need to use its least 3 significant bits to index an eight-bit signal like this (which does not compile):

```
signal somereg : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
...
somereg(hcount and B"00000111") <= <a bit value>;
```

What is the most appropriate way to index the "somereg" vector above?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way than using std_logic_vector and the non-standard `std_logic_arith` and `std_logic_signed` libraries is to `use IEEE.numeric_std.all;` and make the counter `unsigned` (or signed in other contexts where you need negative values).

```
signal hcount  : unsigned(7 downto 0);
```

And you can perform conversions to and from integer, and bitwise operations:

```
hcount <= to_unsigned(123,hcount'length);

signal somereg : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
...
somereg(to_integer(hcount(2 downto 0)) <= <a bit value>;
```

However in the given example, the bitwise operations turn out to be unnecessary: instead of masking bits to extract a 3-bit register address, you could use division and mod operations. Synthesis tools (mostly) aren't stupid : divide and mod by powers of 2 are optimised into the obvious field extractions and don't even generate "and" gates.

```
signal hcount    : natural range 0 to 235;
signal reg_addr  : natural range 0 to 7;

signal somereg : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
...
reg_addr <= hcount mod 8;
somereg(reg_addr) <= <a bit value>;
```

One benefit of this (apart from fewer ugly type conversions) is that you still profit from the integer subtype you declared for `hcount` : incrementing it to 236 will raise an overflow error in simulation, allowing you to catch and correct logic errors early.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there's nothing wrong with using `std_logic_vector` as a counter. I do it all the time. I typically have the following library statements at the top of each module, which give you the necessary arithmetic operators on bit vectors.

```
library IEEE;
  use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
  use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
  use IEEE.std_logic_signed.all;   -- or IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all
```

But if you really want to stay with `integer`, there are standard functions that will convert an integer to other types. In your case, you would use something like

```
somereg <= std_logic_vector (to_unsigned (hcount, somereg'length));
```

`to_unsigned()` is a conversion function that converts the integer into a bit vector, which is why it needs to know the length of the target. Then, `std_logic_vector()` is a simple type-cast of the bit vector.

Comment: I've said it once, and I'll say it again... (depending on your tolerance of "correctness") there *is* something wrong with using `std_logic_vector` as a counter - and that is that [std_logic_arith goes against VHDL's fundamental approach of strong typing](http://parallelpoints.com/numbers-in-vhdl/), and goes against VHDL's fundamental approach of strong typing.  If you want Verilog it's [over there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/verilog)